# How to obtain model parameters of the model from statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Let's consider this simple example of regularized regression:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

model = sm.OLS(y, x)
model = model.fit_regularized(alpha = 10, refit = True, L1_wt = 0.3)
```

What I would like to extract from the model, are the parameters that I used for estimation i.e. Somehow return `alpha: 10`, `refit: True`, `L1_wt: 0.3` in any form that its possible. Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: why do you need it in the result if the params are already available when you fit the model?

Comment: I have a situation, where I load the model from `.pkl` but I don't know the parameters that I estimated it with.